# IOS developer from windows

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine

Do I have to own a Mac to upload games made by unity to the app store?
How to test apps on IOS? Because in android its so easy just build the APK send it to your phone and test, but this cant be done with IOS so how thing work with IOS ?

Comment: _"but this cant be done with IOS so how thing work with IOS ?"_ - of course it can, if you **own a Mac**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need a Mac to upload iOS games made with Unity to submit to Apple for review on the App Store.

Typically, you would:

- Make your game in Unity and test the touch controls right from Unity's editor using the [Unity Remote 4 app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/unity-remote-4/id871767552?mt=8) before building. If you already have Android touch controls working, this should be a piece of cake.
- Enroll in the the [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/). Check out Unity's [Getting Started with iOS Development](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-GettingStarted.html) and [Account Setup](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-accountsetup.html) guides for installing your iOS certificates.
- Build your iOS game from Unity; Unity will create an Xcode project in a folder.
- Open the built folder using Xcode.
- Connect an iPhone or iPad to your Mac; Xcode will detect and let you select the device.
- Click Xcode's Play button and it will build your iOS game onto your device and launch it, allowing you to view console output and memory stats.
- Once you're satisfied it works properly, you need to create an Archive of your build. Do this within Xcode by going Product > Archive.
- Once the Archive is built, open the Organizer window by going Window > Organizer.
- Choose the Archive you built and click "Submit to App Store".